# Reshape list according to tags

Tags: r, reshape

Update:

The data above doesn't really mirror my data, so here is an update:

`tag <- c("\\ID", "\\a", "\\b", "\\ID",  "\\b", "\\ID", "\\a", "\\b", "\\ID", "\\ID")
content <- c("ID_x", "text2", "text3", "ID_y",  "text6", "ID_z", "text7", "text8", "ID_f", "ID_g")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(tag, content))`

I need:

`\ID  \a    \b
ID_x text2  text3
ID_y        text6
ID_z text7  text8
ID_f 
ID_g`

So the unique ID_s don't all have the two variable \a and \b filled in.

I tried `unstack` and also tried `aggreagte` but it doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the `tag` as column names, create a sequence column of 'tag' (`rowid` from `data.table`) and use that in `dcast` to reshape to 'wide'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(tag) ~ tag, value.var = 'content')
```

#### Update

Based on the update, we may need to create a new column 'ind' to mark the occurrence of 'ID'

```
setDT(df)[, cumsum(tag == "\\ID")]
dcast(df, ind ~ tag, value.var = 'content')
#   ind   \\a   \\b \\ID
#1:   1 text2 text3 ID_x
#2:   2  <NA> text6 ID_y
#3:   3 text7 text8 ID_z
#4:   4  <NA>  <NA> ID_f
#5:   5  <NA>  <NA> ID_g
```

---

For the example showed, `unstack` would also work as there are no duplicates

```
unstack(df, content ~ tag)
```

Comment: I have updated the example data. I realized I didn't mention that there are missing varaibles for some unique IDs. Thats why your solution seemed to work at first as the first few elements didn't have missing values. Once i checked the entire document i realized.

Comment: thank you for your help. With the data.set I gave it works perfect, but when I apply it to a different data set, it gives me the result, with every cell filled with 1s only. Also it shows the message "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length' " Any adhoc idea what I should look for? Thx

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi  That is a result of duplicates.  We may need to create a sequence column.  If you can show a small example with that issue, I can update

Answer (score 0):

With the revised question where:

```r
df <- data.frame(tag = c("\\ID", "\\a", "\\b", "\\ID",  "\\b", "\\ID", "\\a", "\\b", "\\ID", "\\ID"), 
                 content = c("ID_x", "text2", "text3", "ID_y",  "text6", "ID_z", "text7", "text8", "ID_f", "ID_g"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The hardest bit is to somehow group the rows by ID. My solution uses `fill` from the `tidyr` library to propagate a value downwards in a data.frame.

```r
library("dplyr")

df %>%
  # Create a proper id column
  mutate(id = ifelse(tag == "\\ID", content, NA)) %>%
  # fill all ids based on the last id observed
  tidyr::fill(id) %>%
  # format the data in the desired shape
  tidyr::spread(tag, content) %>%
  # discarding our now redundant id column and re-arranging columns
  select(-id) %>%
  select(`\\ID`, everything())
```

Result:

```
#   \\ID   \\a   \\b
# 1 ID_f  <NA>  <NA>
# 2 ID_g  <NA>  <NA>
# 3 ID_x text2 text3
# 4 ID_y  <NA> text6
# 5 ID_z text7 text8
```

I think NAs makes the most sense, however if you wanted something else instead, you could simply pass `fill = ""` to `tidyr::spread` to fill missing values with an alternative default, e.g. an empty string `""`.

```
#   \\ID   \\a   \\b
# 1 ID_f            
# 2 ID_g            
# 3 ID_x text2 text3
# 4 ID_y       text6
# 5 ID_z text7 text8
```